# ClipData Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, ormlite

[image]

Doing this [tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-ormlite-with-sqlite-database-tutorial/), and when editing `DatabaseHelper.java` it says `ClipData.Rating.class` can not resolve. Why? How is it possible that for `Item` it works?

These are the setting for Android version. Can it cause issue?

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why?

Presumably, you have an `import` statement for [`android.content.ClipData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html). It does not have static classes named `Rating`, `UserSetting`, or `Message`.

> How is it possible that for Item it works?

Because `android.content.ClipData` *does* have [an `Item` static class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.Item.html).